# Proving the sequence using definition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm having a hard time finding the value for $N$ in this part of the proof.

The Given is {${a_n}$}={$\frac{2^{-n}-2^n}{2^{-n}+2^n}$}, $L=-1$

we must show that the sequence {$\frac{2^{-n}-2^n}{2^{-n}+2^n}$} has a Limit $-1$.

if $n>N$, then $\mid{\frac{2^{-n}-2^n}{2^{-n}+2^n}-(-1)}\mid$ $< \epsilon$

$\iff$ if $n>N$, then $\mid{\frac{2^{-n}-2^n}{2^{-n}+2^n}+1}\mid$ $< \epsilon$

$\iff$ if $n>N$, then $\mid{\frac{2^{-n}-2^n+2^{-n}+2^n}{2^{-n}+2^n}}\mid$ $< \epsilon$

$\iff$ if $n>N$, then $\mid{\frac{2^{-n}+2^{-n}}{2^{-n}+2^n}}\mid$ $< \epsilon$

$\iff$ if $n>N$, then $\mid{1+2^{-2n}}\mid$ $< \epsilon$

$\iff$ if $n>N$, then ${1+\frac{1}{4^n}}$ $< \epsilon$

$\iff$ if $n>N$, then ${\frac{4^n+1}{4^n}}$ $< \epsilon$

Currently Stuck here

Comment: Step number 4 is wrong (i.e. the line with the fourth bi-implication). I cannot see how to reduce the fraction nicely, but you could estimate. For every $n$, we know that $0<2^{-n}< 1$, so you may write
\begin{align*}
|\frac{2^{-n}+2^{-n}}{2^{-n}+2^{n}}| < \frac{2}{2^{n}}
\end{align*}
and this fraction clearly goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the last three steps.  It is impossible to make ${\frac{4^n+1}{4^n}}$ $< \epsilon$.

$\mid{\frac{2^{-n}+2^{-n}}{2^{-n}+2^n}}\mid$ $< \epsilon$ can be writen as $2(2^{-n})<\epsilon (2^{-n}+2^{n})$. Multiplying by $2^{n}$ and dividing by $\epsilon$ we get $\frac  2 {\epsilon} <1+4^{n}$. So just make $4^{n} >\frac 2 {\epsilon}$. Can you finish?

Comment: I know I can take the log of both sides, but where did the '1' go in the inequality$\frac{2}{\epsilon}<1+4^n$

Comment: If $4^{n}>\frac 2 {\epsilon}$ then we also get $1+4^{n}>\frac 2 {\epsilon}$. So choose $N$ such that $n >N$ implies $4^{n}>\frac 2 {\epsilon}$ for $n >N$. @Benny